# How to separate amp-page and not amp-page in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, amp-html

I know when using NextJS, NextJS provide `_document.js` to make global head tag but I want not to use `_document.js`. I have two different pages, let's say it's **Home** and **About** page, I want to make the About page to be an amp-page and the Home as a normal HTML page. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the correct version of Nextjs, you should be able to wrap your page with the `withAmp` higher order component:

```
import { withAmp } from 'next/amp'

...

export default withAmp(Page)
```

If you want the ability to conditionally render components based on whether the page can support Amp or not, you can use `hybrid` and `useAmp` (assuming you write your component as a Function Component).

```
import { withAmp, useAmp } from 'next/amp'


...

const Page = () => {
  const isAmp = useAmp()
  return (
    {isAmp ? <AmpComponent /> : <NonAmpComponent /> }
  )
}

...

export default withAmp(Page, { hybrid: true })
```

However, in my current experience this leads to issues regarding attaching a stylesheet that is often too long for Amp's restrictions. Hopefully, Zeit addresses this in a future release.